# How to pass raw data json format from feature file to stepdefinition file in Cucumber

Tags: java, spring, rest, cucumber

I have input data as json (complex data) format  and want to write cucumber to test rest api. How can I pass input json data from feature file to step definition file. I know how can i pass multiple parameters , but don't know how to pass json data. The input json is very complex and don't know whether i can read it from file in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write the json data in the feature file. Instead give it a name and refer to it by that name in your scenarios.

Then use the name in your step definitions (or helper methods used by step definitions) to get the data.